# What are the CRYSTAL package types?

Tags: crystal, packages

Or, you can point me in the right direction :)

I've found HC49 and variants, but no explanation of what the standard is or what the differences are between the different codes [ex. HC49/US, HC49/S, etc.].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HC49 is not a crystal oscillator package, it is a crystal package. A packaged crystal oscillator has electronics in it and has connections for power, ground, output, and usually a tuning adjustment.

An HC49 package has 2 pins and will just contain a quartz crystal, you have to  connect it to an oscillator circuit.

Here's [a link](http://af4k-crystals.com/RadioCrystals-Holders-Companies-History.htm#holders) with information on some crystal types and holders, including HC49 variants.

Comment: Thank's a million! I've edited the question following your correction.